# Android Emulator not rendering native font

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

So, I have this issue with my emulators on Android Studio, sometimes they doesn't render the font

My emulators sometimes doesn't render the font, this happens with the keyboard, app names but it does not happen with the content of these.
I haven't found a solution other than delete the emulator and create a new one. I've tried different APIs and again it happens, it shows them well the first launches and then nothing.
Does anyone know why it happens or any way to repair them?

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI6zW.png), [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCR9l.png), [image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o91rT.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can sometimes be caused by the renderer / GPU having some sort of incompatibility.

Try changing your OpenGL ES renderer in the emulator settings. I've found "Desktop native OpenGL" to resolve the issue before.
[image: openGL settings]